# 4 digts only regex pattern/group matches dates and slashes

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a programme written in c sharp to extract patterns from a CSV file containing examination results. One of the regex to match a centre number, which contains 4 digits, is matching other strings with slashes i.e. date time strings.
Regex for 4 digits to extract a named group called centreNumber: 
`(?<centreNumber>[0-9]{4})`.

Matches after logging the pattern include:

```
matched centre number -> 6319
matched centre number -> 4/22/2017 6:28:17 PM
matched centre number -> 2016 MALAWI SCHOOL CERTIFICATE OF EDUCATION EXAMINATIONS
```

Sample Input, line by line as per CSV:

```
CENTRE NO: LIKOMA SECONDARY
CAND.ID
0035
4/22/2017 6:28:17 PM
CENTRE NO: LIKOMA SECONDARY
CAND.ID
5035
4/22/2017 6:28:17 PM
CENTRE NO: CHIFUNGA COMMUNITY
CAND.ID
0224
4/22/2017 6:28:46 PM
CENTRE NO: CHIKONDE COMMUNITY
CAND.ID
0238
4/22/2017 6:28:46 PM
```

Expected Output from the sample input above:

```
0035
5035
0224
0238
```

To access the named group I've loaded the Regex in a constant:

```
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filepath);
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            var oneLine = sr.ReadLine();//read single line from csv    
            public const String REGEX_MSCE_CENTRE_NO = @"(?<centreNumber>[0-9]{4})";
            Regex cNoRegex = new Regex(classes.AppConstants.REGEX_MSCE_CENTRE_NO, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            MatchCollection matches = cNoRegex.Matches(oneLine);
             if (matches.Count == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("matched centre number -> " + oneLine);                
                }
}
```

Comment: Your Regex should be fine, please post how you access the named group.

Comment: You probably have other groups around the one you show - this is not the group you are matching as <centreNumber> ... please show a [mre] of your problem including data, call and print of thses results.

Comment: Each of the strings you show has a four-digit number in it; that's what's matching. If you only want to match strings that contain 4 digits, and only 4 digits, preface your pattern (outside the parens) with a circomflex (aka, a hat ('^')), and finish it with a dollar sign ('$'). They represent start and end of the string.

Comment: Why name your capture group `centreNumber` when you're just matching any 4 numbers? Why not name it `any4Numbers`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As also stated in [FLydog57](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4739488/flydog57)'s comment, here we just want to have start and end anchors, and that might likely solve our problem:

```
^[0-9]{4}$
^\d{4}$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nolbYP/1/)

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"^[0-9]{4}$";
        string input = @"6319
4/22/2017 6:28:17 PM
2016 MALAWI SCHOOL CERTIFICATE OF EDUCATION EXAMINATIONS
2016";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

#### [Please see the c# demo here.](https://ideone.com/4rb8aU)

Comment: Could use `"(?m)^[0-9]{4}$"` instead of `options` 